# How to test style of nested component jest-styled-components

Tags: jestjs, styled-components, react-testing-library

Im testing using react-testing-library and jest-styled-components.

I have a wrapper component that renders the styles of its child button dependant on a selected prop passed to it.

This is the code:

```
const selectedStyles = css`
  background-image: url(../image);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border-color: ${color.grey6};
  height: 38px;
  width: 58px;
  & span {
    display: none;
  }
`;

const ButtonWrapper = styled.div`
  & button {
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    ${props =>
      props.selected
        ? css`
            ${selectedStyles}
          `
        : ""}

    &:hover,
    :focus {
      ${props =>
        props.selected
          ? css`
              ${selectedStyles}
            `
          : ""}
    }
  }
`;
```

and the test

```
  test("it renders the correct styles when selected ", () => {
    const { container } = render(<CheckButton selected>Add</CheckButton>);
    const button = container.querySelector("button");
    expect(button).toHaveStyleRule("background-position", "center");

  });
```

but its failing with `"Property 'background-position' not found in style rules"` which is true for the original button, however when its parent is passed the selected prop this style applies.

I am also doing snapshot testing with the component however not testing the props getting passed brings the test coverage down.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

In general as far as nested styles testing is concerned, I would recommend testing directly the nested element.

I personally haven't figured out a way to test nested styles using the ``` .toHaveStyle(``); ``` (not even a simple

```
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

)

so I ended up querying for the exact component I wanted to test, eg:

```
expect(screen.getByText(/text-within-the-child-component/i)).toHaveStyle(`
   text-decoration: none;
`);
```

In your specific case I believe the way to go is to render your component in your test directly with the props that trigger the styles you want for each case (`selected` in your code example).

Answer (score 0):

For those who are facing the same problem `toHaveStyleRule` accept a third "options" parameter after property and value where you can path a modifier:

```
test("it renders the correct styles when selected ", () => {
    render(<CheckButton selected>Add</CheckButton>);
    const button = container.querySelector("button");
    expect(screen.getByText("Add").parentElement).toHaveStyleRule("background-position", "center", { modifier: 'button' });
  });
```

Here I state on the fact that "Add" is the button text and its parent is the component `ButtonWrapper`.
By the way, you should avoid as much as possible using querySelector (here I'm using react testing library).

https://github.com/styled-components/jest-styled-components